# Parse error in my syntax

Tags: php, html, syntax

message error like below

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end
```

we know this error always caused by missing tag of php like ';','}',..I have checked this syntax for two hours but i didn't find what the mistake.

```
<?php
include "config/koneksi.php"; 

$kolom = $_POST['kolom']; 
$kolom1 = $_POST['kolom1']; 
$data = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM tblTrnProduct WHERE (Posisi LIKE '$kolom%' or Posisi LIKE '$kolom1%') Order BY Posisi,ProductName ASC"); 
$n = mssql_num_rows($data);
$no=1;
if($n == "0"){echo "error"; }
else{
$data1 = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM tblTrnProduct where (Posisi LIKE '$kolom%' or Posisi LIKE '$kolom1%') AND ProductName = 'TCA CREAM 65 ML FC 24% A Z A M' ORDER BY Line,PalletNumber ASC");
$n1 = mssql_num_rows($data1);
$j = mssql_fetch_array(mssql_query("SELECT SUM (Quantity) as total FROM tblTrnProduct where (Posisi LIKE '$kolom%' or Posisi LIKE '$kolom1%') AND ProductName = 'TCA CREAM 65 ML FC 24% A Z A M'"));
$jumlah = $j['total'];
if($n1 == "0"){echo" <br><strong>Produk TCA AZZAM tidak ditemukan</strong></br>"; }
else{?>
<div id="print-area-2" class="print-area">
<div style="text-align:right;"><a class="no-print" href="javascript:printDiv('print-area-2');"><font color='#0000CC'><strong> Print </strong></font></a></div>
<br><strong>Produk TCA AZZAM</strong></br><br>
<table border='1' bgcolor='#CCFF66'>
  <thead>   
  <tr>
    <th>Nomor Rak</th>
    <th>Nama Produk</th>
    <th>Kode Produksi</th>
    <th>Line/FM</th>
    <th>Nomor Palet</th>
    <th>Nomor Seri Produk</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<?php while ($d=mssql_fetch_array($data1)){
$Posisi = $d[Posisi];
$ProductName = $d[ProductName];
$ProductionDate = $d[ProductionDate];
$Line = $d[Line];
$PalletNumber = $d[PalletNumber];
$SeriNumber = $d[SeriNumber];
$Quantity = $d[Quantity];
echo"
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><div align='center'>$Posisi</div></td>
    <td><div align='left'>$ProductName</div></td>
    <td><div align='center'>$ProductionDate</div></td>
    <td><div align='center'>$Line</div></td>
    <td><div align='center'>$PalletNumber</div></td>
    <td><div align='center'>$SeriNumber</div></td>
    <td><div align='center'>$Quantity</div></td>
    </tr>";
    $no++;}
echo"<tr>
    <td colspan='6'><div align='center'><strong>Jumlah</strong></div></td>
    <td colspan='2'><div align='center'><strong>$jumlah Carton</strong></div></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>";} ?>
</table></br><br>
<?php
$data2 = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM tblTrnProduct where (Posisi LIKE '$kolom%' or Posisi LIKE '$kolom1%') AND ProductName = 'TCA CREAM 65 ML FC 24% SUN KARA' ORDER BY Line,PalletNumber ASC");
$n2 = mssql_num_rows($data2);
$j = mssql_fetch_array(mssql_query("SELECT SUM (Quantity) as total FROM tblTrnProduct WHERE (Posisi LIKE '$kolom%' or Posisi LIKE '$kolom1%') AND ProductName = 'TCA CREAM 65 ML FC 24% SUN KARA'"));
$jumlah = $j['total'];
if($n2 == "0"){echo"<br><strong>Produk TCA SUN KARA tidak ditemukan</strong></br>"; }
else{ ?>
<strong>Produk TCA SUN KARA</strong>
<table border='1' bgcolor='#CCFF66'>
  <thead>   
  <tr>
    <th>Nomor Rak</th>
    <th>Nama Produk</th>
    <th>Kode Produksi</th>
    <th>Line/FM</th>
    <th>Nomor Palet</th>
    <th>Nomor Seri Produk</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
     </thead>
<?php while ($d=mssql_fetch_array($data2)){
$Posisi = $d[Posisi];
$ProductName = $d[ProductName];
$ProductionDate = $d[ProductionDate];
$Line = $d[Line];
$PalletNumber = $d[PalletNumber];
$SeriNumber = $d[SeriNumber];
$Quantity = $d[Quantity];
echo"
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><div align='center'>$Posisi</div></td>
    <td><div align='left'>$ProductName</div></td>
    <td><div align='center'>$ProductionDate</div></td>
    <td><div align='center'>$Line</div></td>
    <td><div align='center'>$PalletNumber</div></td>
    <td><div align='center'>$SeriNumber</div></td>
    <td><div align='center'>$Quantity</div></td>
    </tr>";
    $no++; }    
echo"
    <tr><td colspan='6'><div align='center'><strong>Jumlah</strong></div></td>
    <td colspan='2'><div align='center'><strong>$jumlah Carton</strong></div></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>"; } ?>
</table></br><br>
<?php $data3 = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM tblTrnProduct where (Posisi LIKE '$kolom%' or Posisi LIKE '$kolom1%') AND ProductKategori = 'BULK PACK' ORDER BY Line,PalletNumber ASC");
$n3 = mssql_num_rows($data3);
$j = mssql_fetch_array(mssql_query("SELECT SUM (Quantity) as total FROM tblTrnProduct where (Posisi LIKE '$kolom%' or Posisi LIKE '$kolom1%') AND ProductKategori = 'BULK PACK'"));
$jumlah = $j['total'];
if($n3 == "0"){echo"<br><strong> Produk BULK PACK tidak ditemukan</strong></br>";}
else{ ?>
<strong>Produk BULK PACK</strong>
<table border='1' bgcolor='#CCFF66'>
  <thead>   
  <tr>
    <th>Nomor Rak</th>
    <th>Nama Produk</th>
    <th>Kode Produksi</th>
    <th>Line/FM</th>
    <th>Nomor Palet</th>
    <th>Nomor Seri Produk</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<?php while ($d=mssql_fetch_array($data3)){
$Posisi = $d[Posisi];
$ProductName = $d[ProductName];
$ProductionDate = $d[ProductionDate];
$Line = $d[Line];
$PalletNumber = $d[PalletNumber];
$SeriNumber = $d[SeriNumber];
$Quantity = $d[Quantity];
echo"
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><div align='center'>$Posisi</div></td>
    <td><div align='left'>$ProductName</div></td>
    <td><div align='center'>$ProductionDate</div></td>
    <td><div align='center'>$Line</div></td>
    <td><div align='center'>$PalletNumber</div></td>
    <td><div align='center'>$SeriNumber</div></td>
    <td><div align='center'>$Quantity</div></td>
    </tr>";
    $no++ ; }
echo"<tr>
    <td colspan='6'><div align='center'><strong>Jumlah</strong></div></td>
    <td colspan='2'><div align='center'><strong>$jumlah Carton</strong></div></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>"; } ?>
</table>
</div></br>
<br><input type='button' value='Back' id='back' onclick='window.location.reload()'></input></br>
<?php} ?>
```

help me to find what the mistake. Thanks...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding a syntax error

Comment: We have seen worse questions then this. Sometimes you need a new set of eyes to find a mistake.

Comment: i copy pasted your code in NetBeans it gave me the same error but its fine after i formatted the code

Comment: i have taken screen shots also of that

Answer (score 3):

Just fix your last line like this:

```
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: That's the only problem I can see as well.

Comment: Tq for the answer, but i have tried that before. Same message error for the result

Comment: Then I doubt that the code you provided is the only code on your page. The parse error could originate in the included file.

Comment: @Sébastien Tq... for your opinion

Answer (score 0):

I think that our last line should be `?>` based on PHP standard:

```
<?php  ?>
```

Hope this help!

Regards!

Comment: What would that do? And would that fix the problem described?

Comment: Yes and no, you just copied the first guy that answered. the last line  needs to close the first else. So `<?php } ?>` is correct. Having `<?php ?>` does nothing.